# Get domain name for any type of URL format? -- PHP to Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a PHP function which properly extracts the domain name **(without any subdomain)** for any given variation of a url. I'm new to Ruby and having a tough time getting it to work:

```
function get_domain_name( $url )
{
    eregi( "http[s]*://([a-zA-Z0-9.-]*)/?.*", $url, $domain );
    $domain = explode( ".", $domain[1] );

    if ( strlen( end($domain) ) == 2 && ( strlen($domain[count($domain)-2]) == 3 || strlen($domain[count($domain)-2]) == 2 )  )
    {
        # special case domains -- ex: co.uk .in .ca
        return strtolower( $domain[count($domain)-3] . "." . $domain[count($domain)-2] . "." . end( $domain ) );
    }
    else
    {
        # regular .com type domains -- three or more letters
        return strtolower( $domain[count($domain)-2] . "." . end( $domain ) );
    }
}
```

Is there something in Rails that do this same thing already?

**UPDATE:**

**Here's what I ended up going with thanks to @BenW**

```
 def extract_domain(url)
    if domain = url.match(/^(http:\/\/)*(www.)*([a-zA-Z0-9.-]*)\/?.*/i)
      domain = domain[3].split('.')
      if (domain.last.length == 2) && (domain[-2].length == 3 || domain[-2].length == 2)
        # special case domains -- ex: co.uk .in .ca
        domain[-3..-1].join('.')
      else
        # regular .com type domains -- three or more letters
        domain[-2..-1].join('.')
      end
    end
  end
```

It accepts all these formats:

```
http://www2.google.com
www2.google.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.google.co.uk
www.google.com
google.co.uk
http://some.long.ass.subdomain.google.com
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) and taking advantage of ruby's [`String#slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
def domain_name(uri)
  Addressable::URI.heuristic_parse(uri, :scheme => "http") \
    .host[/\w+\.\w+(\.\w{2})?\Z/]
end

domain_name("stackoverflow.com") # => stackoverflow.com
domain_name("www.stackoverflow.com") # => stackoverflow.com
domain_name("http://stackoverflow.com") # => stackoverflow.com
domain_name("thing.com.au") # => thing.com.au
domain_name("some.thing.com.au") # => thing.com.au
domain_name("police.gov.uk") # => police.gov.uk
```

Comment: Wow! That is freakin' awesome.

Comment: I'm an ex-PHP dev too. I still marvel at the reduction in code :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing built into the libraries afaik - but a direct port is straightforward

```
 def extract_domain(url)
  require 'uri'
  domain = URI.parse(url).host.split('.')

  raise Exception.new("Invalid host") if domain.length < 2

  if (domain[-1].length == 2) and (domain[-2].length == 3 || domain[-2].length == 2)
    return domain[-3..-1].join('.')
  else
    return domain[-2..-1].join('.')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll run with this. Only problem is that URI fails if no "http://" in the url so doesn't quite allow all variations of user input. A regexp should work around it. Thanks again!

Comment: `URI.parse` puts the domain in the `#path` if there's no scheme.  It's really easy to add the scheme (if it's missing) and move the "path" to the host in such cases, at least using the addressable gem (we do this).

Comment: Oh wow, I just discovered `Addressable::URI` has `#heuristic_parse`, which basically lets you provide hints for the components. `Addressable::URI.heuristic_parse("www.foo.com", :scheme => "http")` (the hint is ignored if it is present in the input).